# Making a Django URL pattern with a variable which isn't a integer

Tags: python, django

I was busy doing the Django tutorials and they explain how you can have url patterns which make it possible to pass information back to the functions in the view.py file. For example

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^some_view/(?P<number>\d+)', views.some_view, name = 'some_view')
```

and the integer in the url slot '(?Pnumber>\d+)' is passed to the some_view function in the file views.py. Apparently the d+ stands for decimal but what should it be if I want to pass a string variable back to the some_views function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use this partern: `(?P<anystring>.+)`

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^some_view/(?P<anystring>.+)', views.some_view, name = 'some_view')
```

Comment: Be aware that this pattern will consume any URL of type `some_view/...` and prevent any other URL from being parsed after that like `some_view/object/id`. You might want to use \w+ instead.

Comment: Yep, but I just using it as example.

Comment: I'm not saying you're wrong. Just cautioning the OP to not use the example as is. :)